# Compare i vs other items in a Python list

Tags: python, list

Good Day, I've googled this question and have found similar answers but not what I am looking for.  I am not sure what the problem is called so I that doesn't help me and I am looking for an elegant solution.

How do I loop over a list, item at a time, and compare it to all other items in a list.  For example, if I had a list

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
```

Each loop of the out would yield something like

1. 1 vs [2,3,4]
2. 2 vs [1,3,4]
3. 3 vs [1,2,4]
4. 4 vs [1,2,3]

One solution I've been playing with involves duplicating the list every iteration, finding the index of the item, deleting it from the duplicate list and compare the two.  This route seems less ideal as you have to create a new list on every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use list comprehension. While still creating a new list every iteration, you don't need to delete an item each time:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
for i in l:
    temp = [item for item in l if item != i]
    print temp

[2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.combiations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to create all combinations of the length 3 from your list and then use `set.defference` method to get the difference element between the `l` and the combinations. but note that you need to convert your main list to a `set` object  :

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> l = {1,2,3,4}
>>> [(l.difference(i).pop(),i) for i in combinations(l,3)]
[(4, (1, 2, 3)), (3, (1, 2, 4)), (2, (1, 3, 4)), (1, (2, 3, 4))]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to use two loops:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]

for i in arr:
    comp = []
    for j in arr:
        if i != j:
            comp.append(j)
    print(comp)
```